# I cannot pass a (String-)value to another class's setter method

Tags: java, attributes, setter

I know that i have not written a catch block yet.(reason?, but i think it's actually not the problem; the attributes of the "Game" class are perfectly changeable)

I always get an IOException when i try to call the setName method in Player (even if I set "name" in Player to public and change it directly).

```
    public class game{



    protected static int amountPlayers;
    protected static Player[] playerList = new Player[amountPlayers];

public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{
        //Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String input;

        System.out.println("new round? (1 for yes; enter for no):");
        int boo = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        if (boo == 1) {
          Rounds.setNew(true);
        } // end of if

        if (Rounds.getNew() == true) {
          //SavingManagement.createFile();                            
          System.out.println("# of players:");
          int amount = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
          setAmountPlayers(amount);
        } // end of if

        for (int i = 0; i < amountPlayers; i++) {
          System.out.println("Name player No. " + (i + 1) + ":");
          input = br.readLine();
          playerList[i].setName(input);      
        } // end of for
        }


    public class Player {


      protected static int score;     
      protected static String name = "";



      public static void setName(String input) {
        name = input;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Show the exact exception with stacktrace, where it happens and what is the input causing it. In other words, provide a [mcve]

Comment: Whenever I try to enter anything to setName in the for- loop, I get :    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: and the only part of the code which is mentioned in the error is the last line (playerList[i].setName(input);).

Comment: Instead of using a separate variable, `amountPlayers`, use `playerList.length`. Also, that array is initalized to have a length of zero

Comment: @Natecat I now initialized the array after setting the value for amountPlayers, but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that you are providing the valid size in `amountPlayers`, by writing the following statement you are just creating the Player array and not initializing it.

```
protected static int amountPlayers = 100;

/* This will just create the array */
protected static Player[] playerList = new Player[amountPlayers];
```

Before you can use `setName()`, you'll have to initialize the array as follows:

```
for(int x = 0; x < amountPlayers; x++) {
    playerList[x] = new Player();
}
```

OR you can do something like this:

```
/* Create a new object of class Player */
Player myPlayer = new Player();

/* Set Name */ 
myPlayer.setName(input); 

/* Assign it to your array */
playerList[i] = myPlayer;
```

Comment: OK, I got it. I am now initializing every single object before the setting. Thang you, I forgot about initializing o_o

Comment: @user3672075 Your Welcome! :)

Answer (score -1):

Do you need the Player class as a public inner class?
Do you need to protoct the score and the Name?

Otherwise this should work:

```
public class game {

    protected static int amountPlayers;
    protected static Player[] playerList = new Player[amountPlayers];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < amountPlayers; i++) {
            playerList[i].setName("test");
        }
    }
}

class Player {
    private int score;
    private String name = "";

    public void setName(String input) {
        name = input;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried to make the whole of Player non-static, but the result is the same...

Answer (score -2):

The `PlayerList` contains Player objects, so when you are calling the `setName` method like this:  `playerList[i].setName(input)` it is through an instance of class Player, but the method is actually static and should be called in this way:

```
Player.setName()
```

Although, the best thing you could do is add a constructor in class `Player`, add new Player objects in the array `playerList` and make the method `setName()` and the other variables in class Player non-static.